# How to draw short cv2.line in opencv-python?

Tags: opencv

If the two points to draw the line are (100,100) and (200,200), is there a way to draw only the middle point?

Comment: do you need to mark the middle point?

Comment: Draw a radius=1 circle at 150,150 or draw a line from 149,149 to 150,150.

Comment: `C++` or `Python`? If you search for "opencv set pixel C++/python" you'll get lots of answers, assuming you mean you just want to set the pixel (150, 150).

Comment: I want to find the shortest point possible. I use python. On the image, I have at (352, 92)
(-2.5121140e+06, 4.8845758e+02) It has two points like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly your problem you want only the middle point so this snippet should be solving your problem

```
import cv2

def midpoint(point1, point2):
    # values need to be rounded to an integer to avoid an error when calling cv2.circle() later
    midpoint_x = round((point2[0] + point1[0])/2)
    midpoint_y = round((point2[1] + point1[1])/2)
    midpoint = (midpoint_x, midpoint_y)
    return midpoint

img = cv2.imread('image.jpg')
    
point1 = (352, 92)
point2 = (-2.5121140e+06, 4.8845758e+02)
    
point3 = midpoint(point1, point2)

# starting with radius 10 to make the point initially more visible
img = cv2.circle(img, point3, radius=10, color=(255, 255, 255), thickness=-1)
cv2.imshow("Midpoint position", img)
cv2.waitKey()
cv2.destroyWindow("Midpoint position")
```